# Partially Porting PJLIB - Without IOQUEUE, select abstraction, and socket abstraction API

Tags: c, sip, voip, porting, pjsip

I would like to use the PJSIP library to implement a small SIP softphone on an embedded system. Since this embedded system does not offer Linux or support POSIX, I would like to port the PJLIB library only partially, as described here (https://www.pjsip.org/porting.htm#mozTocId30930). The threading function can be deactivated via a macro, but I'm not quite sure yet how I have to set up this new transport function or where exactly it has to be included so that I can also bypass the IOQUEUE implementation and the PJLIB socket abstraction.

On my embedded system (Keil RTX) I can allocate a UDP socket and register a callback which is called on a network event. I also have a send function which I can use to send data packets. Although I have already looked into the stack, I can't find a way to get started.

Has anyone already dared to the partial porting and can give me a brief assistance. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

See how Symbian port worked (I think it might be removed from recent versions, but it should be still downloadable) - it was also based on non-POSIX sockets.  Create your own platform-specific socket file and ioqueue file.